# Creating a Tooltip that knows what platform is currently being used

Tags: dynamic, mac-os-x, interface

I have *Mathematica* 8 on my PC. I also have a new Mac with CDF-player, but not *Mathematica*. I want a `Tooltip` that shows one thing if running on a PC, and something different if running on a Mac. Both of the following show `"MS-Windows"` in the `Tooltip` even when using my Mac.

```
Tooltip["A String",
If[StringMatchQ[$Version,__~~"Windows"~~__],"MS-Windows",(* else Mac *)"Probably OS X"]
]

Tooltip["A String",
If[SystemInformation["FrontEnd","MachineType"]==="PC","MS-Windows",(* else Mac *)"Probably OS X"]
]
```

It will be even better if it can hande a third case where the OS is neither Windows or OS X. Can you show me how to do it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think the answer is related to choosing `$OperatingSystem` or `SystemInformation` as in Mr.Wizard's and F'x's answers (although both are cleaner than using `$Version`). I'm guessing you created your file on your PC and then opened it in your Mac. `Tooltip` then shows you the cached result from your PC. To make the tooltip refresh on your other machines, simply make it a `Dynamic` one. I would do:

```
Dynamic@Tooltip["A String", $OperatingSystem]
```

Answer (score 5):

How about using [`$OperatingSystem`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/%24OperatingSystem.html)?

> Typical values for $OperatingSystem are "Windows", "MacOSX" and "Unix".

```
$OperatingSystem
```

> ```
> "Windows"
> ```

Comment: This is the best criteria to use. However, failure to use Dynamic (See RM's solution) is real cause of my problem.

Answer (score 3):

What if you try using `SystemInformation["Kernel", "OperatingSystem"]` instead of matching `$Version`? On my Mac, I get:

```
In[1]:= SystemInformation["Kernel", "OperatingSystem"]
Out[1]= "MacOSX"
```

Comment: I undid my vote for this answer as I don't know if there is any advantage to this over `$OperatingSystem` -- if there is I will gladly restore my vote.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I presume if you connect to a remote kernel, the answer will be different.